# Is there a way to find progress completion of ObjImporter drawing mesh in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, progress-bar, .obj

In my Unity project, I want to have a progress bar that starts loading when I import a .obj model during runtime.

How I want to it work is when I press "spacebar", the ObjImporter would start importing/drawing the assigned model and during that period of time while it's drawing, there would be a progress bar somewhere that shows the completion of the importing+/drawing progress, so the user could see the estimated amount of time neededto complete and not get impatient.

I'm using a slightly modified ObjImporter.cs from unity wiki:

```
/* This version of ObjImporter first reads through the entire file, getting a count of how large
 * the final arrays will be, and then uses standard arrays for everything (as opposed to ArrayLists
 * or any other fancy things). 
 */

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public class ObjImporter : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject spawnPoint;
    public GameObject emptyPrefabWithMeshRenderer;
    public string meshPath;
    public GameObject spawnedPrefab;
    public float progressPercentage;

    int noOfLines;

    void Start ()
    {
        progressPercentage = 0;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("space")){
            Mesh importedMesh = GetComponent<ObjImporter>().ImportFile(meshPath);
            noOfLines = TotalLines(meshPath);
            spawnedPrefab=Instantiate(emptyPrefabWithMeshRenderer,spawnPoint.transform.position,spawnPoint.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            spawnedPrefab.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh=importedMesh;
            spawnedPrefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(Random.value, Random.value, Random.value, 1.0f);
        }
    }

    private struct meshStruct
    {
        public Vector3[] vertices;
        public Vector3[] normals;
        public Vector2[] uv;
        public Vector2[] uv1;
        public Vector2[] uv2;
        public int[] triangles;
        public int[] faceVerts;
        public int[] faceUVs;
        public Vector3[] faceData;
        public string name;
        public string fileName;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    public Mesh ImportFile (string filePath){
        meshStruct newMesh = createMeshStruct(filePath);
        populateMeshStruct(ref newMesh);

        Vector3[] newVerts = new Vector3[newMesh.faceData.Length];
        Vector2[] newUVs = new Vector2[newMesh.faceData.Length];
        Vector3[] newNormals = new Vector3[newMesh.faceData.Length];
        int i = 0;
        /* The following foreach loops through the facedata and assigns the appropriate vertex, uv, or normal
         * for the appropriate Unity mesh array.
         */
        foreach (Vector3 v in newMesh.faceData)
        {
            newVerts[i] = newMesh.vertices[(int)v.x - 1];
            if (v.y >= 1)
                newUVs[i] = newMesh.uv[(int)v.y - 1];

            if (v.z >= 1)
                newNormals[i] = newMesh.normals[(int)v.z - 1];
            i++;
        }

        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

        mesh.vertices = newVerts;
        mesh.uv = newUVs;
        mesh.normals = newNormals;
        mesh.triangles = newMesh.triangles;

        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
        mesh.Optimize ();

        return mesh;
    }

    private int TotalLines(string filePath)
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (r.ReadLine() != null)
            {
                i++;
            }
            return i;
        }
    }

    private static meshStruct createMeshStruct(string filename)
    {
        int triangles = 0;
        int vertices = 0;
        int vt = 0;
        int vn = 0;
        int face = 0;
        meshStruct mesh = new meshStruct();
        mesh.fileName = filename;

        // Read and retrieve all the text in the file.
        StreamReader stream = File.OpenText(filename);
        string entireText = stream.ReadToEnd();
        stream.Close(); // End of stream.

        // Going through the retrieved text.
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(entireText))
        {
            string currentText = reader.ReadLine();
            char[] splitIdentifier = { ' ' };
            string[] brokenString;
            while (currentText != null)
            {
                if (!currentText.StartsWith("f ") && !currentText.StartsWith("v ") && !currentText.StartsWith("vt ")
                    && !currentText.StartsWith("vn "))
                {
                    currentText = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (currentText != null)
                    {
                        currentText = currentText.Replace("  ", " ");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    currentText = currentText.Trim();                           // Trim the current line
                    brokenString = currentText.Split(splitIdentifier, 50);      // Split the line into an array, separating the original line by blank spaces
                    switch (brokenString[0])
                    {
                    case "v":
                        vertices++;
                        break;
                    case "vt":
                        vt++;
                        break;
                    case "vn":
                        vn++;
                        break;
                    case "f":
                        face = face + brokenString.Length - 1;
                        triangles = triangles + 3 * (brokenString.Length - 2); /*brokenString.Length is 3 or greater since a face must have at least
                                                                                     3 vertices.  For each additional vertice, there is an additional
                                                                                     triangle in the mesh (hence this formula).*/
                        break;
                    }
                    currentText = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (currentText != null)
                    {
                        currentText = currentText.Replace("  ", " ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mesh.triangles = new int[triangles];
        mesh.vertices = new Vector3[vertices];
        mesh.uv = new Vector2[vt];
        mesh.normals = new Vector3[vn];
        mesh.faceData = new Vector3[face];
        return mesh;
    }

    private static void populateMeshStruct(ref meshStruct mesh)
    {
        StreamReader stream = File.OpenText(mesh.fileName);
        string entireText = stream.ReadToEnd();
        stream.Close();
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(entireText))
        {
            string currentText = reader.ReadLine();

            char[] splitIdentifier = { ' ' };
            char[] splitIdentifier2 = { '/' };
            string[] brokenString;
            string[] brokenBrokenString;
            int f = 0;
            int f2 = 0;
            int v = 0;
            int vn = 0;
            int vt = 0;
            int vt1 = 0;
            int vt2 = 0;
            while (currentText != null)
            {
                if (!currentText.StartsWith("f ") && !currentText.StartsWith("v ") && !currentText.StartsWith("vt ") &&
                    !currentText.StartsWith("vn ") && !currentText.StartsWith("g ") && !currentText.StartsWith("usemtl ") &&
                    !currentText.StartsWith("mtllib ") && !currentText.StartsWith("vt1 ") && !currentText.StartsWith("vt2 ") &&
                    !currentText.StartsWith("vc ") && !currentText.StartsWith("usemap "))
                {
                    currentText = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (currentText != null)
                    {
                        currentText = currentText.Replace("  ", " ");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    currentText = currentText.Trim();
                    brokenString = currentText.Split(splitIdentifier, 50);
                    switch (brokenString[0])
                    {
                    case "g":
                        break;
                    case "usemtl":
                        break;
                    case "usemap":
                        break;
                    case "mtllib":
                        break;
                    case "v":
                        mesh.vertices[v] = new Vector3(System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[1]), System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[2]),
                                                       System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[3]));
                        v++;
                        break;
                    case "vt":
                        mesh.uv[vt] = new Vector2(System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[1]), System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[2]));
                        vt++;
                        break;
                    case "vt1":
                        mesh.uv[vt1] = new Vector2(System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[1]), System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[2]));
                        vt1++;
                        break;
                    case "vt2":
                        mesh.uv[vt2] = new Vector2(System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[1]), System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[2]));
                        vt2++;
                        break;
                    case "vn":
                        mesh.normals[vn] = new Vector3(System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[1]), System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[2]),
                                                       System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[3]));
                        vn++;
                        break;
                    case "vc":
                        break;
                    case "f":

                        int j = 1;
                        List<int> intArray = new List<int>();
                        while (j < brokenString.Length && ("" + brokenString[j]).Length > 0)
                        {
                            Vector3 temp = new Vector3();
                            brokenBrokenString = brokenString[j].Split(splitIdentifier2, 3);    //Separate the face into individual components (vert, uv, normal)
                            temp.x = System.Convert.ToInt32(brokenBrokenString[0]);
                            if (brokenBrokenString.Length > 1)                                  //Some .obj files skip UV and normal
                            {
                                if (brokenBrokenString[1] != "")                                    //Some .obj files skip the uv and not the normal
                                {
                                    temp.y = System.Convert.ToInt32(brokenBrokenString[1]);
                                }
                                temp.z = System.Convert.ToInt32(brokenBrokenString[2]);
                            }
                            j++;

                            mesh.faceData[f2] = temp;
                            intArray.Add(f2);
                            f2++;
                        }
                        j = 1;
                        while (j + 2 < brokenString.Length)     //Create triangles out of the face data.  There will generally be more than 1 triangle per face.
                        {
                            mesh.triangles[f] = intArray[0];
                            f++;
                            mesh.triangles[f] = intArray[j];
                            f++;
                            mesh.triangles[f] = intArray[j+1];
                            f++;

                            j++;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    currentText = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (currentText != null)
                    {
                        currentText = currentText.Replace("  ", " ");       //Some .obj files insert double spaces, this removes them.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label (new Rect (20, 20, 100, 100), noOfLines.ToString());
    }
}
```

This is a simple ProgressBar.cs I wrote:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ProgressBar : MonoBehaviour {

    float progress;
    Vector2 pos;
    Vector2 size;
    public Texture2D barBG;
    public Texture2D barLoad;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        progress = 0;
        pos = new Vector2 (20, 40);
        size = new Vector2 (100, 10);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        progress = Time.time * 0.05f; // Place holder.
    }

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(pos.x, pos.y, size.x, size.y), barBG); 
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(pos.x, pos.y, size.x * Mathf.Clamp01(progress), size.y), barLoad);
    }
}
```

I have looked everywhere for a method in finding out progress completion of file reading+drawing of mesh and couldn't find one.

I've tried having the progressBar load respectively to the number of lines in the .obj file, but it isn't working too well as reading is way faster than the actual drawing of the mesh.

I'm out of ideas, anyone know of any way? Thanks in advance!